# Order by a substring of column 2 then by column 1 bash

Tags: bash, shell

My file looks like this:

```
0.3 test_a1
0.2 test_a1
0.4 test_a1
0.1 test_a21
0.9 test_a21
0.5 test_a21
0.3 test_b99
0.2 test_b99
```

Each group is column 2 without the number at the end (in the above example the two groups are test_a and test_b). I want to order by group then order by column 1 so the correct result is:

```
0.1 test_a21
0.2 test_a1
0.3 test_a1
0.4 test_a1
0.5 test_a21
0.9 test_a21
0.2 test_b99
0.3 test_b99
```

The following command gives the wrong result:

```
sort -t' ' -k2,2 -k1 file.txt

0.2 test_a1
0.3 test_a1
0.4 test_a1
0.1 test_a21
0.5 test_a21
0.9 test_a21
0.2 test_b99
0.3 test_b99
```

How can I achieve the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -k2,2.7
```

Result

```
0.1 test_a21
0.2 test_a1
0.3 test_a1
0.4 test_a1
0.5 test_a21
0.9 test_a21
0.2 test_b99
0.3 test_b99
```